# Is there an R function for finding a list of all dates between two values. then inserting them as rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
Contract_Begin  Contract_End  FP
2020-01-01       2020-01-31   5
2020-01-01       2020-03-31   6
```

If the Contract_End - Contract_Begin is less than 1 month, I want to insert the additional months as rows below.  Here is the desired output.

```
Contract_Begin   Contract_End   FP
2020-01-01        2020-01-31    5
2020-01-01                      6
2020-02-01                      6
2020-03-01                      6
```

Trying to accomplish in R as a part of pre data processing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps `library(dplyr)library(purrr);library(tidyr); df1 %>% mutate_at(1:2,  as.Date) %>% mutate(Contract_Begin = map2(Contract_Begin,  Contract_End, seq, by = "1 month")) %>% unnest(c(Contract_Begin))`

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `map2` to get the sequence of dates from 'Contract_Begin','Contract_End' and then `unnest` the `list`column created by `map2` and expand the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate_at(1:2, as.Date) %>% 
   mutate(Contract_Begin = map2(Contract_Begin, Contract_End, seq,
            by = "1 month")) %>%
   unnest(c(Contract_Begin))
```

Comment: I'm finding this code is very inefficient when working with a large dataset.  Any ideas on how to speed it up?

Comment: @TimBatten You can change it to `data.table` i.e. `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[, Map(seq, MoreArgs = list(by = "1 month"), as.Date(Contract_Begin), as.Date(Contract_End))]`